# Search for text1 AND text2 in a line of file.txt

Tags: batch-file, cmd, find, findstr

I am trying to return results only for lines that contain matching text via cmd.

In this case the line must match in both "Name" and "Surname".

Read though http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html, and tried the first example

findstr "James Henry" sam.txt >sam2.txt

Unfortunately, this also returns all lines that contain just James and just Henry in them. Only a the line which contains "James" and "Henry" should be returned.

**example line that should be returned**

James Edgar Henry 228559

**example line that should not be returned**

James Peters 148825

Any assistance appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot be sure if the two words stand together or the order might be unsure, you will have to search for both of them separately:

```
findstr /i "\<James\>" sam1.txt | findstr /i "\<Henry\>" sam2.txt
```

`\<`means "start of a word", `\>` means "end of a word, so you are sure, NOT to find a guy named "Henry Jamesson"

Comment: You wont believe how much of a headache this has been. Your solution works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use the `/C` switch for literal string searching:

```
findstr /C:"James Henry" sam.txt >sam2.txt
```

You may need to specify `/I` as well if you want insensitive searches.

This is described in `findstr /?`:

> Use spaces to separate multiple search strings unless the argument is prefixed with /C.  For example, `'FINDSTR "hello there" x.y'` searches for "hello" or "there" in file x.y.  `'FINDSTR /C:"hello there" x.y'` searches for "hello there" in file x.y.

---

Okay, after reading your revised question, it sounds like you need to use regular expressions:

```
findstr /R "James.*Henry" sam.txt >sam2.txt
```

If you also need to find names like "Henry Tiberius James" then I'd suggest either using a search file:

```
findstr /R /G:search.txt sam.txt >sam2.txt
```

With `search.txt` as:

```
James.*Henry
Henry.*James
```

Or using a better scripting language like PowerShell.

Comment: I did the /C: option but this only returns a complete matching string unless I did something wrong there (James Henry will return, but not James Edgar Henry, which should also return). I added some examples in the Question, Thanks

Comment: @David I've added to my answer.

Comment: I appreciate the effort. Your solution works as well. Better to have more than one way of doing something :). Will up vote your answer. Thank you